# What's the best practice on downloading multiple file in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a PHP based database for storing forms and images. The images and thumbnails are indexed in the Db and stored in different folders.
Upon request, the user can search and queue these data, showed in a PHP page.
I am implementing a way for users to download these images.
I figured the approach of Zipping them into one single file to be the easiest / user friendliest.

So, what's the best practice?

1- to generate a zip file serverside. That creates an acceptable CPU usage, and I can't figure out the risk of leaving these temp files behind

Or

2- Generating the Zip file on the fly, to directly download the. To the client?

If a even better solution is available please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would you generate the zip file on the fly without that being serverside?

Comment: Whatever method you would eventually use you will need to set up a cronjob to delete and files that are older than x hours/days.

Comment: @jeff Unless you simply generate the ZIP on the fly and pipe it to stdout (to the client), then no such file ever exists in the first place.

Comment: Yes, @deceze. I was thinking something like that. But maybe the cronjob will do the job. Maybe I'll set the server to delete all user generate zip files upon upon session logout AND set a periodic cronjob cleanup for old .ZIP files.